# Subdomains and Resources In Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain, rails-routing

I Have a site that is split into three units(subdomains):

```
example.com # Main Site
archive.example.com # Searchable Archive
admin.example.com # CMS
```

At the bottom of `config/routes.rb` I'm mapping the subdomains and root as follows:

```
  match "/" => "archive#index", constraints: {subdomain: "archive"}
  match "/" => "admin#index", constraints: {subdomain: "admin"}
  root :to => "pages#index
```

I have a number of resources which are currently declared like:

```
  resources :users
  resources :themes
  resources :downloads
```

With this setup, the resources are available in all subdomains, so for the `users` resource the following are all valid:

```
archive.example.com/users
admin.example.com/users
example.com/users
```

**How do I set up my routes so that `users` are only available under an admin subdomain?**
*Visiting `archive.example.com/users` or `example.com/users` should result in a Routing Error.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
  resources :users
end
```